# Is there a way to type a non-URL value (URL without protocol http/https) to address bar in chrome browser in Selenium(java)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a validation to perform where some text needs to be entered in the address bar which will redirect me to some page. I then need to capture the current URL and verify it with the expected URL value.

**Ways I've tried so far**

- `driver.get(https://www.google.com);`
- Using Robot class I got control of the address bar

```
    Robot rb = new Robot();
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
```

- Now I need to send keys to address bar. E.g.- 'SELENIUM' and when I hit the enter button it will redirect me to some page. Here I need to capture the URL of the page and verify with my expected value.
  3a. To send keys I tried following ways but it didn't work:

```
Action action = new Actions (driver);
actions.sendKeys("mytext");
```

- I also tried it with Java Script Executor but seems I need locators for that and I can't locate address bar as it can't be inspected.[PFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgXDI.png)

Comment: have you tried executing a script that sets document.location?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it's didn't work. I was also thinking of using 'Point' (Java) class to get coordinates but it also requires locators. Unfortunately I am in need of some solution where locators aren't required as address bar can not be inspected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why you would need to validate literally entering the text into the address bar. I think you may be misinterpreting the requirement. The address bar belongs to the browser, not your application so I don't believe it is something you need to test.

You should just use driver.get() and validate the page has loaded by using driver.findElement() on something unique to the new page and then check if that element is displayed/enabled. If you really want to get the URL then you can do driver.getCurrentURL().

Comment: We have some vanity URLs to validate and those are formed as - *"ApplicationName/VanityEndPoint"*. Upon hitting this non-URL value; it takes us to a page which is linked to this vanity end point. 

For eg - Vanity end point is '/PIZZA' so it will take you to a pizza home page and that's what my validation is that I need to capture URL and validate whether it's a Pizza URL.

Comment: So just to clarify, your goal is to capture the URL in order to verify the page has loaded? If this is true then please read my answer on how to verify the page has loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 

I am not able to load the URL in the first place. Validation comes later :) 

First I need to load a non-URL value in the address bar and this is where I am stuck at. driver.get() / driver.navigate().to() are throwing invalid argument error on passing a non-URL value. It only accepts URLs with the protocol.

Comment: Why cant you just put the protocol before the vanity URL? Is it not effectively doing this anyway in the background when you try search without the protocol in the URL address bar?

Comment: Okay I think I understand now but im not sure why you have been told to test the vanity URL like this. It really doesnt make any sense, once you search using the vanity URL then of course it will change to the full URL? If you want to assert against the URL then do it against the full URL, that is what will tell you if the vanity URL actually worked. You create test, the vanity URL can be hardcoded into the test, you know that you are using the vanity URL so after you click search you can look for the full URL, this is perfectly fine, I dont believe what you are trying to do is possible.